# Ping fails after adding route

Tags: linux, networking, routing

This is my current routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
```

I can ping host 192.168.0.2:

```
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=7.26 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=2.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1.02 ms
```

However if I add a specific route for that host, it becomes unreachable:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.2/32 dev enp0s3` 

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
192.168.0.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp0s3

PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.2.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.2.15 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.2.15 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I can't understand why. I'm working on Linux Ubuntu 17.10 running on VirtualBox, network configured as NAT. Host machine runs Windows 10.

Comment: looks like a bad gateway configuration. show us a diagram of how your box, the 10. network, and the 192. network are connected.

Comment: @FrankThomas The guest has address 192.168.0.1. It is connected to a 192.168.0.2 device with an Ethernet hub. No gateways on that network. VirtualBox networking via NAT, that's the 10.0.2.0 network. It works well without adding the route, I'm trying to understand why adding that route breaks this configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this makes sense is that your network is configured like this:

```
[Physical Device (192.168.0.2]----[HUB]-----[Physical Host(192.168.0.1)]-----[Virtual Machine (10.0.2.x)]
```

Your default route...

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
```

...tells the computer that all traffic not destined to the directly connected (10.0.2.x) network should be sent to the gateway device with the hostname "gateway."

This works great.

It quits working when you add...

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp0s3
```

...because you just told the computer to send all traffic destined to the IP address 192.168.0.2 to a gateway device with the IP address `0.0.0.0` which isn't valid.

**The gateway is `gateway` not `0.0.0.0`.**

Comment: Thanks, I did not knew that `gateway` in the Gateway column of the routing table was actually a host name... I just don't know from where it comes from, I suppose it is from VirtualBox itself. Of course I should have used `route -n` instead...